# Symfony 4 + Doctrine strange issue when pulling relationships from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I keep experiencing a strange issue with doctrine in Symfony 4. Quite often when I pull an entity from the database the relationships on some are just null, yet the database clearly shows the mapped id. It tends to happen more often with OneToOne relationships.

So I'll make up a quick example:

```
class EntityA implements \JsonSerializable
{


    /**
    * @var int
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var EntityB
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityB", inversedBy="entityA")
    */
    private $entityB;

    /**
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
    */
    private $name = 'Entity A';

    public function setId(int $id) : self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId() : int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName(string $name = 'Entity A') : self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setEntityB(?EntityB $b) : self
    {
        $this->entityB = $b;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntityB() : ?EntityB
    {
        return $this->entityB;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() : array
    {

        return [
            'id'   => $this->getId(),
            'name' => $this->getEntityB()->getName()
        ];
    }


}
```

```
    class EntityB implements \JsonSerializable
    {

        /**
        * @var int
        * @ORM\Id()
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
        private $id;

        /**
        * @param EntityA
        * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityA", mappedBy="entityB")
        */
        private $entityA;

        /**
        * @var string
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
        */
        private $name = 'Entity B';

        public function setId(int $id) : self
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getId() : int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setName(string $name = 'Entity B') : self
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getName() : string
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function jsonSerialize() : array
        {

            return [
                'id'=>$this->getId(),
                'name'=>$this->getEntityA()->getName()
            ];
        }

    }
```

Just basic, I didn't bother commenting all methods, but now if I pull an entity A from the database and then serialise it:

```
/** @var EntityARepository $aRepo */
$aRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(EntityA:Class);

$entityA = $aRepo->findOneBy(['id'=>1]);

$entityASerialised = json_encode($entityA);
```

I'd expect an array back where by "name" has entity B name in there, which works sometimes and not others. Keep having issues where in this case while serialising entity A the mapping of `$entityB` is null ??

Why would it be null when the mapping is correct? One minute in one call it will be fine and `$entityA->getEntityB()` will return the EntityB relationship, the next it will just be null for no reason?

Comment: You mean that if you call exactly the same code several times in a row, always fetching the exact same entity, you will get different/inconsisten results?

Comment: Yes. I’ve experienced this for example pulling the entity once then the relationship mapping is fine, I could then pull it again further down the same function and the mapping is then null. This is happening quite often especially when serialising the entity

Answer (score 0):

By initializing the tables using the doctrine commands and using your example code I was not able to reproduce your issue.

You haven't provided any information about which entity owns the field containing the id of the other.
So adding a JoinColumn to the entity which contains that field might solve your issue:

```php
/**
 * @var EntityB
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityB", inversedBy="entityA")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entityB;
```

Comment: Do you know, I actually thought of this last night. The real entities are much larger with multiple similar relationships. I’m wondering if the join column name is conflicting as it will be the same across multiple entities. I’m going to give your suggestion a try and specifically define the column names so they’re unique. I’ll let you know if it works.